# How to Create Microsoft Access Database in C#?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

How can I create a ms access database in C#?
I have created an application using which I can drain some specific information about hardware and software now I want to create a database and write those information to an Access database file!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used c# to create a database, but this maybe helpful:
https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/kb/149558

I have used an existing Access database in combination with c#.

The connectionprovider below may vary on the Access version. Here are some connectionstrings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

```
//Making the connection
string databaseLocation = "location";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + databaseLocation);

//Opening the connection
con.Open();

//Making a command
OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand("query",con);

//Execute a select query
OleDbDataReader reader = odc.ExecuteReader();

//Example of retrieving data from select query
while(reader.Read())
{
   string result = reader.getString(0);
}

//Execute different query (examples: insert into, update, delete)
odc.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Closing the connection
con.Close();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Do I need any sort of reference to bring OLEDconnection !?

Comment: thanks pal! but i found the an easier answer in the duplicate of my question! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I think you'll need a reference. Right klik on it, then resolve and it should display the reference you need. No problem. Glad I could help!